# unable to publish result to pact broker

Tags: post, verification, provider, consumer, pact-broker

I am trying to publish verification result on pact broker host on localhost:9292 using the below command:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@/home/ec2-user/pact-ruby/example/zoo-app/spec/pacts/zoo_app-animal_service.json ${verification_url}
```

Here , i am unable to fetch the value of verification url from below syntax.

```
BASE_URL="http://localhost:9292"

response_body=$(curl ${BASE_URL}/pacts/provider/Bar/consumer/Foo/latest)
verification_url=$(echo "${response_body}" | ruby -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.parse(ARGF.read)['_links']['pb:publish-verification-results']['href']")
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@script/foo-bar-verification.json ${verification_url}
```

Currently i have performed verification at the below url:
`../animal-service > specs/service_consumers> rake:pact-verify-at[]`.

i am unable to figure out how will i retrieve the verification url from the above request. what am i missing, please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways Provider can verify published pact from Pact Broker.

1. A webhook '*contract content changed*' is setup on Pact Broker itself that calls Provider's verification build by passing `${pactbroker.pactUrl}` to it.
2. The Broker requires you to assign a consumer version `${commit_hash}` for every contract you publish. When running a provider verification the provider needs to specify the consumer version it wants to verify. The broker will then return the latest version of the contracts for that specific consumer version.